# Onclick in a hyperlink aloha editor does not work on chrome

Tags: onclick

I  integrate aloha editor in my page. while i click on image its show image toolbar of aloha editor but i want to perform onclick event on specific image.

Below is my code

```
<a href="#" onclick="RemoveThisDiv('levle5');" class="hlink"><img style="cursor:pointer;" src="http://domainname/images/fancy_close.png" align="right" title="Delete" /></a>
```

when i click on image onclick event does not be invoke only in chrome and safari

but in firefox its work fine.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with background image for your copy buttons! Hope It will help you!